# ROS Indigo installation: rosdep init failed

Tags: python, urllib2, ros

When I am installing ROS Indigo following the installation guide under Ubuntu 14.04, I am stuck at the step "Initialize rosdep".
I use the `sudo rosdep init` command but an error occurred saying

> ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
>   Website may be down.

Similar problem can be found on the Internet but the strange thing is I can successfully access this link through the browser or using wget command in the terminal.

Can someone help me solve the problem?

I also notice that using `req=urllib2.openurl(xxx)` under python, I cannot get any response from any github link such as github dot com or xxx dot git

I am not very familiar with python  but could it be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing happened to me during installation and "sudo rosdep init".
Tried different suggestions but the one solved my problem is simply switched my wifi to another hot-spot. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could solve it as follow:

```
sudo apt install -y ca-certificates
sudo rosdep init
```